# Laravel extending creation model

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to extend when the creation of a model happens.

The model called `Competition` that has the following function:

```
public function Team(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team');
}
```

now on creation of an `Competition`, I want to add in a pivot table for every user in the team an value.
how can I do this?

I tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array()){
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    foreach($this->Team->Users as $user){
        // insert some data in table
    }
}
```

that would give me the following error when going to a page:
[image: Error page]

**EDIT:**
I figured out that this isn't the way to go, this get's called even when no objects are created, so I have to find the Create command for an model (not researched this yet)

Comment: Give more information about your `_construct` please.

Comment: Please post your models and tables schemas

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had to do this in the __Construct();

I had to do this in create():

```
public static function create(array $attributes){
    $var= parent::create($attributes);

    // code
}
```